# Hide Status Bar in Android with Phonegap Build

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, web-applications, phonegap-build

I have enabled fullscreen in the config.xml file but when the keyboard appears ,status bar is shown also and stays there unless i tap on it.There is a way to avoid this in Ios but i haven't find anything for android.At least can i tap the status bar programmaticaly with jquery?

Comment: check this plugin https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar

Comment: It's not on the phonegap build plugin's list!

Comment: Good question, I'm having the same trouble. The "Fullscreen" option in the config.xml seems to have a new meaning since cordova android platform 5.x.

Answer (score 7):

You can try setting

```
<preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />
```

in the config.xml

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue and what fixed this for me was adding this line to the `config.xml` file:

```
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="true" />
```

Then updating my code on PGB.

Comment: This is also for iOS

Answer (score 2):

1. Install StatusBar plugin:

   `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar`
2. Update `config.xml`:

   `<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugin.statusbar" />`
3. Hide bar on startup or when you need it.

   `StatusBar.hide();`

See https://github.com/phonegap-build/StatusBarPlugin plugin for more information.

Comment: This is for iOS

Answer (score 1):

I tried removing:

`<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#ee6e73" />`

from config.xml - no joy. Tried adding:

`<preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />`

to config.xml - also no joy. Inverting:

`<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />`

to

`<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="true" />`

provided no solution. In all cases, the status bar shows with the keyboard, but doesn't ever go away. Ended up solving it with JavaScript:

`$("body").on("blur.app", "input", StatusBar.hide);`

The status bar still shows with the keyboard, but is dismissed with the blur event.

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked to install the latest version, see [this updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36641179/status-bar-hide-cordova):

Actually, there is a fix for cordova-plugin-statusbar that has been committed on github and should land in version 2.1.4+  To get the latest cordova-plugin-statusbar now, type

cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar.git
The statusbar should now stay hidden when interacting with inputs, keyboard etc.

Comment: please add more details to your answer