# Status Bar Hide Cordova

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

If I remove the status bar, every time I open the keyboard (
or a notification arrives) there is a bug.

```
   App.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
        $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
          if(window.StatusBar) {     
            StatusBar.hide();
          }
        });
    });
```

[image]
[image: Image1]

Any suggestion? Thank you!

Comment: What is the plugin version, i.e. what is the output of `cordova plugins`? Did you try the latest version? `cordova plugin rm statusbar && cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar`

Comment: Version 2.1.2 of the status bar plugin

Comment: Does the master version work the same way?

Comment: Yes, I have the same problem with the master... 
Does somebody has resolved this problem ?

Answer (score 8):

**Updated:**

Actually, there is a fix for **cordova-plugin-statusbar** that has been committed on github and should land in version **2.1.4+** (i.e. you don't need an additional plugin like my original answer stated). To get the latest **cordova-plugin-statusbar** now, type

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar.git
```

The statusbar should now stay hidden when interacting with inputs, keyboard etc.

**Original Answer:**

I fixed it with the plugin [cordova-plugin-fullscreen](https://github.com/mesmotronic/cordova-plugin-fullscreen)

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-fullscreen
```

Then, after `deviceready`:

```
StatusBar.hide();
if (typeof AndroidFullScreen !== 'undefined') {   // Fullscreen plugin exists ?
  function errorFunction(error) { console.error(error); }
  AndroidFullScreen.isSupported(AndroidFullScreen.immersiveMode, errorFunction);
}
```

ImmersiveMode keeps it hidden while interacting with inputs, keyboard etc.

Note: as per the [cordova-plugin-fullscreen](https://github.com/mesmotronic/cordova-plugin-fullscreen) docs, this method is only supported on **Android 4.4+**. There is also a 'lean mode' for Android 4.0+, but this shows the status bar while interacting (not ideal)