# Hide Navigation Bar on Android 4.2, PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova, phaser-framework, android-fullscreen

I'm developing a little game with Phaser.io and trying to build it like a native app with PhoneGap. On devices with on-screen buttons the navigation bar is covering some part of the game world. I successfully implemented the Immersive mode but it only works on android 4.4+, so the question is: how can I hide the navigation bar in an app built with PhoneGap on device running Android 4.2? Thanks in advance to you all

Answer (score 0):

You can find a question like yours [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35826580/6691908) but all resumes into installing [this plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar)

Comment: I already tested it but it refers to the status bar (in the top of the screen), I refer to the bar in the bottom of the screen where there are back home and menu on-screen buttons

Comment: if it works on android 4.4+ did you tried the corss walk plugin? https://crosswalk-project.org/ maybe it can help you

Comment: you mean build the game with crosswalk instead of phonegap? i don't think it can help, is more like an Android-related problem than Phonegap