# Hide Status Bar in Android with Phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, phonegap-build, phonegap

I would like to hide statusbar on Android.

On startup, I don't have statusbar but a grey bar with size of statusbar on the top.
And when i use keyboard, the statusbar appears.

I already check theses answers but it don't fixed my problem : [Hide Status Bar in Android with Phonegap Build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35826580/hide-status-bar-in-android-with-phonegap-build)

Here my `config.xml` :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.phonegap.helloworld" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <name>Hello world</name>
    <description></description>
    <author email="" href="http://phonegap.com"></author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="landscape" />
    <preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />

    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" spec="~1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" source="npm" spec="~1.1.6" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-fullscreen" spec="~1.1.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="~2.4.2" />

    <config-file parent="UIStatusBarHidden">
        <true/>
    </config-file>
    <config-file parent="UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance">
        <false/>
    </config-file>

    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />

    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    <engine name="android" spec="~6.3.0" />
</widget>
```

I also put this code on `JS`:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    StatusBar.hide();
    if (typeof AndroidFullScreen !== 'undefined') {   // Fullscreen plugin exists ?
        function errorFunction(error) { console.error(error); }
        AndroidFullScreen.isSupported(AndroidFullScreen.immersiveMode, errorFunction);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this issue, I add this preference on my config.xml:

```
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="true" />
```